# Get item from ng-repeat in nested directive based on html from content-objects

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to develop an application in angular that will return a html page from objects with inners.
When i add an ng-repeat attribute on an element i don't have access to the item from the collection in the inner elements.
Because each inner element have a new instance of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt all this is the best way to go but it works.
In the controller:

```
    $scope.collectionItem = $scope.$parent.collectionItem;
```